rsync - compare base on file content and not file size/modification time and then only update those files and their timestamp
I'm working on a deploy script and it gets code from git clone then doing rsync. I want the rsync to only update files that the content are different and not base on file size and modify time. I tried rsync -ai src dest and the output seems to include files that has no change but the files from git clone has the newer timestamp so I think it included those ones.
I tried -aci and seems not work too as all the files in dest have new modify timestamp even there's no change in the actual content.
So that's why I wonder if it can update only by file content?

only update files that the content are different and not base on file size and modify time why would the content change and not the modification date?

Greg Askew Yes the files that have content different have new modify date. But I'm saying those files have the same content(no change) also have newer modify timestamp as the source are from git clone so it has new timestamp as if they're new created. I just want the files get updated when the files content are different and keeps the same modify time for those ones have no change.

You should rephrase and ask how to use rsync to copy only changed files.

The -a rsync option includes -t which means preserve modification times. So, if -c finds that a file that is unchanged, it won't rewrite it, but the -t will change the modification time to that of the source.
You can use -a --no-t -c to disable the -t, but then files that get updated due to a checksum difference will be given a modification time of now, rather than the time of the source file.
